# Estimate of exponential of a normal Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I have following excercice:

[Excercice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJFsR.png) (where H is a Hilbert-space)
so far we have introduced the normal functional calculus, but not the holomorphic.
my idea was to put $f_t(z):=e^{tz}$ and use this Lemma:

[Lemma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeUSW.png)
Now let R be close to ||A|| and proceeded:
$\|f_t(A)\| = \| \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{|w|=R} R_A(w) f_t(w) dw\| $
$\leq \frac{1}{2 \pi} 2 R \pi \sup_{z \in \delta B(0,R)} \|R_A(z) \| \sup_{z \in \delta B(0,R)} \| e^{tz}\| $

In the lecture we had $\|R_A(z)\|=\frac{1}{dist(z,(\sigma ))}$ and since R is close to ||A|| we can further estimate:

$\leq \sup_{z \in \delta B(0,R)}|e^{t re(z)}|$

now my idea was to let R go to ||A|| but I dont see how this helps.
Am I on the right track? Or maybe using the series expansion would yield a better result?

kind regards

Comment: If $A$ is normal and $f$ is continuous on $\sigma(A)$, then $\|f(A)\| =\sup_{z\in\sigma(A)}|f(\lambda)|$